# ESRI JavaScript API - Using WebGL

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am building a dojo app using the ESRI JavaScript version 4.5. I built it using these instructions from ESRI:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/using-bower/

I'm trying to render my feature layers with WebGL. In order to do this, I need to include this script tag before loading the JavaScript API into the app:

```
<script>
  var dojoConfig = {
    has: {
      "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
    }
  }
</script>
```

I downloaded the ESRI JavaScript API to my machine, so I don't have to load it into the app. Where do I include this script tag to make WebGL work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you check out the sample application in the [jsapi-resources](https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/4.x/bower/dojo) repo.

You'll want to add that flag in the [`defaultConfig`](https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/blob/master/4.x/bower/dojo/build.profile.js#L277) of the Dojo build profile. In that sample, the flag is set to `0`, so you can just change it to `1` when you do your build.

Hope that helps!